# Как получить первый элемент модели используя отношения и ресурсы

Tags: php, laravel

`Мой Controller`

```
    public function index()
    {
          return AdvertResource::collection(Advert::with('image')
              ->paginate(10));
    }
```

`Мой AdvertResource`

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'image' => AdvertImgResource::collection($this->image),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at
        ];
    }
```

`Мой AdvertImgResource`

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'path' => $this->path,
        ];
    }
```

На выходе я получаю это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У каждого объявления есть несколько фотографий, мне нужно выводить главную фотографию (первая в списке) Подскажите можно ли вывести первый элемент массива path для каждого объекта?
Так же это должно быть внутри метода index, потому что в методе show я буду получать полноценно все элементы.

Comment: Добавляйте код кодом, а не скрином

Comment: @Pashok готово!

Comment: @Bob `with('image')`, лимитьте тут в своём методе `image()` или забирайте одну связь...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar в случае с методом show как быть?) Там я должен выводить все ссылки на изображения внутри каждого объявления

Comment: @Bob `with(['image' => function($q) => { $q->limit(1); }])`. Но вообще это 2 разных метода должно быть. Один тянет hasOne отношение, другой тянет hasMany отношение.